# for loop with sleep between iterations

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a gigatic nested for loop that needs to sleep every 1s on every iteration of the `nested loop` or `else block`. This is usually performed with code like this:

```
for (let i=1; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        alert("hello world");
    }, i*3000 );
}
```

I'm reading this is too memory intensive and it should not be used.

This is my code so far:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    if (this.data[i].dataTypes.length > 0) {
      for (var j = 0; this.data[i].dataTypes.length; j++) {
        //performed each second
        this.setData(this.data[i].dataName, this.data[i].dataTypes[j]);
      }
    } else {
      //performed each second
      this.setData(this.data[i].dataName, "");
    }
  }
```

How should I rewrite it to so that the nested loop, or else block gets executed every second?

Comment: But my array is over 20000 entries long. Surely thats not the way to go.

Comment: You can use recursion if you are not a big fan of using `for` loops, but either ways are quite efficient.

Comment: So setting 20000 setTimeouts in code is okay? :)

Comment: Just use one setTimeout and iterate the items each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like for loops, you can either do

```
function sleep(n){
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, n));
}

async function doStuff(){
    for(let element of myList){
        doMoreStuff();
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/y7m0qv51/

or

```
function doStuff(i){
    doMoreStuff(myList[i]);
    setTimeout(() => doStuff(i + 1), 1000);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rh8m6h94/

But you should realize that none of these are considered more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this involves using setTimeout() as a form of tail-end recursion.

For example

```
var index = 0
var process = function() {
       if( something )  {
        do_something();
      } else {
        do_something_else();
      }
     index = index + 1;
     if( index < this.data.length ) {
         setTimeout( process, 1000 );
     }
};
process();
```

Be aware that 'this' is a little finicky, with respect to callbacks.  You might
need to use 'setTimeout( process.bind(this), 1000 )' to ensure 'this' is correctly set within the callback.